# C++ Why program with extern instance referenced before defined compiles and links

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

The problem can be shown on a simple example:

```
extern A<bool> a;
B b(a);
A<bool> a("a");
```

In header file:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    public:
        A(const char * name) : m_name(name) {}

        const char * name() const {
            return m_name;
        }
        ...
        ...
    private:
        const char * m_name;
};

class B {
    public:
        B(A<bool> & a) {
            printf("%s = %p\n", a.name(), &a);
        }
};
```

The code actually compiles, links and produce:

```
(null) = 0044F604
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qSrH5F)

I wonder if this shouldn't be caught by compiler and fail.

Compiler in question is `gcc 9.2.0 (mingw-w64-i686)`.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. The code-snippet you show won't build without major modifications.

Comment: What should be caught by compiler? usage of globals? Behave as intended. zero-initialization followed by dynamic initialization... Joyce of globals.

Comment: @rustyx this is not really the static initialisation order problem. The order here is well defined (`b` then `a`). It just happens to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, global objects within the same translation unit are initialized in the order they are defined (though the order across TU's is [undefined](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use)). See [[basic.start.init]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.init#2):

> ... Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their definitions in the translation unit.

On the other hand, *storage* for objects of static storage duration is allocated at program loading time, so each global object has an address from the beginning.

In general in C++ it is allowed to *reference* a not-yet-initialized object, but *accessing* it is undefined behavior. Generally no diagnostic is required for undefined behavior.

In your case, `B` can be constructed with a reference to `A`, and it can save the passed-in reference to be used later:

```
class B {
    A<bool> & a_;
    public:
        B(A<bool> & a) : a_(a) { }

        void run() {
            printf("%s = %p\n", a_.name(), &a_);
        }
};
```

Comment: Got it! Compiler checking the initialization order in a single TU would be an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is nothing wrong with passing around and using references to uninitialised objects. The standard explicitly allows this.
2. It is the programmer's responsibility to use such a reference in one of the limited ways permitted by the standard. The compiler is not required to complain if usage falls outside of the permitted range. Instead, the behaviour of a program that does this is undefined.

See [basic.life/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6) and [basic.life/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7) for detailed information.